# How to Double-Buffer JLayeredPane

Tags: java, flicker, doublebuffered, jlayeredpane, double-buffering

I am currently making a path-laying Tile game in Java where I am using a JLayeredPane with multiple layers. The game runs fine, but everytime the repaint method is called, the entire pane flickers.

Right now I have the game running on a timer where every tick automatically moves the character one tile at a time along the path in which I have laid out. Naturally, I would need to update the screen in order to reflect the changes to the user, but the problem is that the repaint method forces a redraw on all layers of the LayeredPane. Every tick would cause a flicker on the map area of the screen. While it is bearable, I would just like to get rid of it so it looks nicer.

I have researched on the use of double buffering and have even set the option to double buffer the pane to true as well (e.g. pane.setDoubleBuffered(true)), but have had no luck with various implementations. Is there a way to just draw the entire pane with all layers for every tick in an outside buffer, then copy it in one go over to the main screen?

Thank you

Comment: Swing components are double buffered by default, without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would simply be impossible to diganose the problem

Comment: I am currently breaking down my code to get a basic example to look at. I might not be able to get one to you until later as I work on my game during my weekends if I have spare time (busy work and student life...) :D